# Vote count rapidly changing for question and its answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I was just on this question ([What is wrong with this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350210/whats-is-wrong-with-this)), using OSX 10.7/ Chrome 19, and the vote numbers kept 'flickering' to different numbers 4-6 times a second, usually within +/-2 votes from what it started at. There was no change in the expanded vote count, and this happened with the questions vote count and some of the answers vote count as well.

Just for clarity's sake, the question's vote count changed from 2->3->4->3->4->2->3 every second, for 1-3 seconds. Even after refreshing the page, this still occurs. It starts intermittenly in the first minute or so of page load

Comment: There's also **something** odd going **on** with **random** bold parts. ;-)

Comment: Someone is probably playing with the vote button.

Comment: @Arjan I've always done that on SO to make it easier for people to skim my posts, but I don't frequent meta very often, so it might come off wrong here. sorry bout that

Comment: Well, I find **it annoying** on SO too. (Just makes me feel folks think that *their* answer is more important than those of others... But that's just an opinion, of course.)

Comment: @Arjan by the way, this is most definitely no relation to the link you posted

Comment: Errr, I think it answers it. You're seeing the live update (and like Mystical wrote: maybe someone is just clicking the buttons), what else is there to it?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I missed the most important part: *"no change in the expanded vote count"* -- why wasn't that bolded? ;-) Still @Mysticial is right I guess, that could be an answer then?

Comment: @Arjan how does bolding selective text within a question imply that the question itself is more important than others? I do this as well to assist readability for people already reading my question, not to draw attention to my question as a whole. Bolding and other formatting does not show up in the question list, so it's not like paying for bold or other nonsense on eBay to make your question stand out. Can you explain how using the facilities we have to format question text means we think our question is more important than other questions?

Comment: I wrote "answers", @Aaron. (But that doesn't mean I like excessive formatting in questions either.)

Comment: @Arjan ok, still I don't see how adding emphasis to part of my answer means I am trying to make my answer stand out as opposed to making that salient point more readable or more likely to be picked up when skimming.

Comment: Sure, @Aaron, selective is not always excessive. But if almost every line has some formatting ([or worse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350161/jframe-in-java-jframe-addbutton/11350316#11350316)) then that bothers me.

Comment: @Arjan then you should be careful to **qualify your criticisms** lest they sound like **sweeping generalizations**.

Comment: Well, "it" in my second comment (to which you responded) referred to what I called random formatting (and a smiley), @Aaron, at that point not knowing where these comments would end.

Comment: @Arjan I think that's definitely subjective. Reviewing the revision history, if I read just the bold parts, I understand exactly the crux of the issue the OP is bringing to light. I understand your objection to random bolding, but please apply it where there is actually random bolding. As your comment stands, I feel that people will take it that they should completely stop using formatting for emphasis, and in some cases that would be unfortunate because I, for one, find it quite useful.

Comment: @Arjan note also that some readers will not necessarily associate your two comments. I didn't until you brought it up just now... previously I just saw "it" as a reference to Joe's comment justifying bolding in general. So again, please be careful to **quality criticisms** that might apply to a larger use case than an unacknowledged reference to some previous comment.

Comment: Very well, @Aaron, like I also wrote: it is just an opinion. Not sure if the bolding in your 19:04 UTC comment was just a joke or not, but in my opinion that example is annoying too: I truly feel that in the list of comments those bolded words are not any more important than the other comments—but it does make that comment stand out. And I seriously also found the bolding in the question not helpful. That's all!

Comment: @Arjan It is no less of a joke than your initial comment, which inadvertently started all of this time-suck in the first place.

Comment: Well, @Aaron, I respect your opinion, like I said mine is just an opinion too. Subjective: yes, I never said otherwise though I get the feeling you think I did? Even more, in all my comments I use words like "I feel" and "just an opinion". Hence, I'm not sure who you're blaming for "this time-suck", but I don't feel responsible for that! As an aside: I browsed through a dozen of your SO posts and did not see any annoying formatting in those. I hardly saw *any* bold. Very nice posts, from what I can tell.

Comment: (Joe, sorry for all these Inbox notifications!)

Comment: @Arjan my objection was to this comment in isolation: "Well, I find it annoying on SO too." Which to the casual reader might imply that using bold, in general, is not well accepted. Newer users have no idea if your opinion is commonly held or not, and may not read all of the surrounding context. Especially if I had *not* commented about it. So I'm just trying to raise awareness that you should be careful about how your comments appear *in isolation* and how they might be perceived if someone like me is too lazy to read the context or not smart enough to understand the correlation.

Comment: @Aaron, I wish that *"I find [..] But that's just an opinion, of course"* would be understood as *"we, the people"* in my daily life ;-) Okay, I'll keep it in mind. My feedback to you: people glancing the above list might [see your bolded comment stand out](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q3ef.png) and in isolation might think I've done something totally wrong. Cheers!

Comment: @Arjan No worries. I stayed up way too late last night, and at the very least it is giving my something fresh to read to keep me awake at work :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somebody was either playing with the vote buttons or was changing their mind very quickly.

I've seen it happen before, where someone clicks up and down repeatedly many times. The result is that the vote count will flicker between 3 values. (in your case, 2-4)

It's normal, don't worry about. If a dev looks at the uncollapsed vote-history, there will a LOT of upvote/unupvote/downvote/undownvote events.